# Do we want hats?

Tags: discussion, events

Last year, as a promotional effort, Stack Exchange ran an event called "Hat Dash", on [Arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com), Stack Exchange's Gaming Q&A site, where users earned hats for their avatars for performing certain actions on the site.

[image: Hats!]

They're offering the same event again, except this year, they're extending the event to any Stack Exchange community that would like to participate.

The hats they'll offer this year include things like a fedora with a feather pen, for those gifted individuals who fix our posts via editing, and they'll be other types of hats for other actions. The hats shown above were all from last year's event.

These hats will be somewhat holiday-themed and may even be a bit goofy.

**Details:**

- The event will run from December 19th to January 4th.
- Users can see their entire hat collection at http://winterba.sh/
- People who don't want to participate can "opt-out" and continue to view the site as normal, sans hats. Just click the "I hate hats" option, which will be in the footer of the site during the event. :(
- The only change to PMSE will be the hats on users' avatars, and the infamous "I hate hats" link in the footer.
- We'll let the community management team know if we'd like to participate or not on Friday, November 23rd, based on the community response to this post. :)

**So what say you, PMSE community!?  *Do we want hats?* Upvote this post if you do want hats, and downvote if you loathe them.**

---

[image: Users page with hats]

Comment: haaaaaaaaaaaaaats are the best! :D

Answer (score 6):

**Upvoted!**

I guess that's not a problem to have some fun during Xtmas time... some hats will add another (funny) way of saying 'thanks!' to our community :)

It's just another (temporary) kind of badge... and is there anyone around who does *NOT* like badges?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's not much interest in hats at this point. I'd propose we set a deadline of Wednesday, 21 November to get more feedback. Then, if we don't hear anything to the contrary, we opt-out.

UPDATE
Sounds like the general feeling is that there's no harm in giving it a go.

Comment: I was thinking the opposite, that if we don't hear anything, we opt-in. I feel like decisions made in meta should involve whomever is there at the time, so unless you really just don't like hats, we should reconsider. ;)

Comment: +1 for the deadline setting. It looks like something funny, if I can turn it off if it isn't funny anymore, I'm in.

Comment: Do you think it could turn people off/be too confusing (e.g. "what is this hat thing that I have to deal with???")?

Comment: Nope, PM's are pretty smart people. We're not dealing with an audience of mouth-breathers here. lol ;)  The worst that will happen is we might get some meta questions asking what it's about, and if Ebinezer does show up in one of the posts, we can point him to the "I hate hats" link at the bottom, and then he can go back to counting his money and forgetting all about Tiny Tim and Stack Exchange's silly Hat Dash. ;)

Comment: Do it. Do it! I was only here because I thought, "Oh, look, there's a meta site here too! I wonder what's going on there?" So most users probably don't think to look here. Forgiveness over permission :)

Comment: Lunivore, the deed is done and hats should be on their way.