# HoHoHo! Hat Dash 2014 is here! Are we in?

Tags: discussion, events

Since 2012, as a promotional effort, Stack Exchange runs an event called "Hat Dash", which almost every site in the Stack Exchange network participated in, where users earned hats for their avatars for performing certain actions on the site.

[image: Hats!]

These hats will likely be somewhat holiday-themed and may even be a bit goofy.

In [2012](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/q/535/430) and [2013](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/q/635/430) we asked our community if we're up to hats, so here we are again asking what do we think about having it in 2014 :)

**Details:**

- This event will run from 15 December 2014 to 4 January 2015. Users will be able to see their entire hat collection on winterbash2014.stackexchange.com. That site will also have a landing page, explaining the rules and other details of the event.
- Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an “I hate hats” option available. And just like last time, at the end of the event, all hats will go back into storage.
- The only visual change to the Stack Exchange sites themselves will be the presence of the hats and the “I hate hats” button in the footer.
- We'll let the community management team know that we plan to participate on Wednesday, November 26th, unless there is an overwhelming number of community members who strongly feel such an idea isn't in our best interests.

**So what say you, PMSE community!?  *Do we want hats?* Upvote this post if you do want hats, and downvote if you loathe them.**

---

[image: Top Users page, with hats]

***Screenshot of the [Winterbash Leaderboard](http://winterba.sh) as it looked in 2012.***