# Lots of edits recently

Tags: discussion, editing

I've noticed a lot of edits coming through recently and while I want to applaud the improvements to the questions, I'm a bit concerned that so many are being edited that new open questions are being pushed out of sight. Is there a way to viewing the newer questions without recent edits pushing them off the top that I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way to viewing the newer questions

You have the option to sort questions page by *newest* posts.

`http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest`

> [image]

---

> I've noticed a lot of edits coming through recently

Probably due to the hats of [Winter Bash 2015](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/748/hohoho-winter-bash-2015-is-here).